# How can I get this If-statement to return true?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling to get a true return value from an if-statement.

I have debugged every possible way and I still didn't get a true return from the following if-statement:

```
if (document.getElementById('U1').style.background == 'white') {
   document.getElementById('U1').style.background = 'limegreen';
} else {
    document.getElementById('U1').style.background = 'blue';
  }
```

So, I am checking if the style background on the U1 is white, which is set in my CSS file. But, I always get a false return i.e. blue background. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Add `console.log(document.getElementById('U1').style.background);` before this if statement. Does it definitely return 'white'?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I assume you want to toggle the background-color. If that is the case you should use the `backgroundColor` instead of `background` property, like so:

```
if (document.getElementById('U1').style.backgroundColor == 'white') {
   document.getElementById('U1').style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
} else {
   document.getElementById('U1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

[More about the backgroundColor property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp)

Comment: Did you initially set the background-color in a css-file or in an inline-style-tag? That might make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('U1').style.background` is going to check the style attribute on the element, not the style in style sheets or that gets rendered.
To get the style rendered you can use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
var u1 = document.getElementById('U1')
let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(u1);
if (compStyles.getPropertyValue('background') == 'white') {
    u1.style.background = 'limegreen';
} else {
    u1.style.background = 'blue';
}
```

Comment: I get the following error with your code: Cannot access 'compStyles' before 
initialization at HTMLButtonElement. This is full click-event code:
   document.getElementById('U1').addEventListener('click', function() {
     var u1 = document.getElementById('U1');
     let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(u1);
     if (compStyles.getPropertyValue('background') == 'white') {
       u1.style.background = 'limegreen';
     } else {
       u1.style.background = 'blue';
     }
   
   });

Answer (score 0):

Use backgroundColor instead of background in IF condition

```
if (document.getElementById('demo').style.backgroundColor == 'yellow') {
document.getElementById('demo').style.background = 'limegreen';
} else {
    document.getElementById('demo').style.background = 'blue';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by first setting the style in the script and then comparing, maybe not the most efficient but it works. Here is the code:

```
var u1 = document.getElementById('U1');
u1.style.background = 'white';
document.getElementById('U1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (u1.style.background == 'white') {
    u1.style.background = 'limegreen';
  } else if (u1.style.background == 'limegreen') {
    u1.style.background = 'red';
  } else if (u1.style.background == 'red') {
    u1.style.background = 'blue';
  } else if (u1.style.background == 'blue') {
    u1.style.background = 'orange';
  } else if (u1.style.background == 'orange'){
    u1.style.background = 'yellow';
  } else if (u1.style.background == 'yellow') {
    u1.style.background = 'white';
  }
});
```

If you didn't understand before this lets me cycle through colours when I press a button.